# Passing a PHP array in a SOAP call

Tags: php, xml, arrays, soap

So I am trying to include the following XML in my SOAP request:

```
<Responses>
    <Response>
        <QuestionAnswerID>someint</QuestionAnswerID>
        <QuestionID>someint</QuestionID>
    </Response>
    <Response>
        <QuestionAnswerID>someint</QuestionAnswerID>
        <QuestionID>someint</QuestionID>
    </Response>
</Responses>
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577795/passing-array-to-soap-function-in-php) posting, which is vaguely on the same topic, but it produces output like so:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["Responses"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
        ["Response"]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
                ["QuestionAnswerID"]=>
                int(someint)
                ["QuestionID"]=>
                int(someint)
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
                ["QuestionAnswerID"]=>
                int(someint)
                ["SurveyQuestionID"]=>
                int(someint)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with that is that the arrays now have indices, which the web service I'm calling appears to not like.  Any way I can generate something like the above XML?

TIA.

Comment: Someone just posted this on one of my questions.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/… ;)

Comment: Thanks.. I hadn't been doing that. Guess I'll start now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to test this without a SOAP server with your WSDL to go against. You should be able to create associative arrays like so:

```
$responses = array();
$responses[] = array("QuestionAnswerID" => someint, "QuestionID" => someint);
$responses[] = array("QuestionAnswerID" => someint, "QuestionID" => someint);

$response = array("Response" => $responses);

$soapData = array("Responses" => $response);
```