# Passing multiple variables to server with PHP and SOAP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, soap

I wonder if it's possible to send multiple variables at once to the server? For example:

```
$client->AddTheseValues($a, $b, $c);
```

The server/MySQL would then add those values into the database:

```
public function AddTheseValues($a, $b, $c) {

$this->sql = "INSERT INTO `records` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES
     ('{$a}','{$b}','{$c}');";

$result = mysql_query($this->sql);

}
```

The above procedure doesn't seem to work with me; I'm only able to send ONE variable at time. When I send more than one, the database won't get updated and weirdly I get no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array.

```
$responses = array();
$responses[] = array("QuestionAnswerID" => someint, "QuestionID" => someint);
$responses[] = array("QuestionAnswerID" => someint, "QuestionID" => someint);

$response = array("Response" => $responses);

$soapData = array("Responses" => $response);
```

Source of the code above [Passing a PHP array in a SOAP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338573/passing-a-php-array-in-a-soap-call)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, you're guiding me to the right direction... But how about if I want to add variables inside an array? I read that it isn't possible in PHP5.