# php soapclient call params

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I need to transform the above call in php and the particularity is that in the call it is mandatory to have three params in the same argument:

```
<v20:searchItem>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>customer_id</arg0>
         <arg1>table_name</arg1>
         <arg3><field_name>Barcode</field_name><value>record_id</value></arg3>
         <arg3><field_name>DOC_DATE min</field_name><value>date_min</value></arg3>
         <arg3><field_name>DOC_DATE max</field_name><value>date_max</value></arg3>
         <arg4></arg4>
         <arg5>0</arg5>
         <arg6>1000</arg6>
      </v20:searchItem>
```

My code is:

```
$myParams1 = array('field_name' => 'Barcode',
                                  'value' => $barcode);
$myParams2 = array('field_name' => 'DOC_DATE min',
                                  'value' => $datai);
$myParams3 = array('field_name' => 'DOC_DATE max',
                                  'value' => $newdate);
$params = array(
    "arg0" => $sasAliasSP,  
    "arg1" => $sasAliasDA,
    "arg2" => "",
    "arg3" =>$myParams1,
    "arg3" =>$myParams2,
    "arg3" =>$myParams3,
    "arg4" => "",
    "arg5" => "0",
    "arg6" => "1000"
);
```

but is not working, can you please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774498/6564057

arg3 needs to be an array with ascending keys starting with 0, so my code now is:

```
$myParams[] = array('nome_Campo' => 'Barcode', 'valore' => $barcode);
$myParams[] = array('nome_Campo' => 'DOC_DATE min', 'valore' => $datai);
$myParams[] = array('nome_Campo' => 'DOC_DATE max', 'valore' => $newdate);

$params = array(
    "arg0" => $sasAliasSP,  
    "arg1" => $sasAliasDA,
    "arg2" => "",
    "arg3" => $myParams,
    "arg4" => "",
    "arg5" => "0",
    "arg6" => "1000"
);
```

and it works like charms.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$params = array(
    "arg0" => $sasAliasSP,  
    "arg1" => $sasAliasDA,
    "arg2" => "",
    "arg3" => array($myParams1, $myParams2, $myParams3),
    "arg4" => "",
    "arg5" => "0",
    "arg6" => "1000"
);
```

Comment: thank you very much, I already tried that but it's still not working because their params are on three different lines and this solution gives one "arg3"

Comment: Post result from `__getLastRequest()` in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the last request, I don't think they have trace option on for security reason. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Then how do you know that my solution gives one arg3?

Comment: And why don't you turn the trace on? You can do this in SoapClient constructor.

Comment: I can't turn trace on, it gives me an error. I think they disabled the function server side cause it's a legal archive. I var_dump the array and it gives only one arg3. I'll post the result asap. Thank you

Comment: Array structure is not the same as resulting request structure, so this var_dump does not tell you how many `arg3`s are in the request. Try to get the request by overloading `SoapClient::__doRequest` in derived class.