# Incomplete content in SOAP request

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am very new to SOAP request and I am trying to figure out how this works.

I am trying to make a request for a Sales Order Object.
This is the wsdl code that I received:

```
<s:element name="Start">
<s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="company" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="orders" type="tns:ArrayOfSalesOrdersSalesOrder" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfSalesOrdersSalesOrder">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SalesOrdersSalesOrder" nillable="true">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="CustomerNumber" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="OrderNumber" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Currency" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="CustomerComment" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="OrderReference" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="FirstName" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="LastName" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Street" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="ZipCode" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="City" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Country" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Discount" type="s:decimal" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="ChargeHeader">
                        <s:complexType>
                            <s:sequence>
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Code" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Value" type="s:decimal" />
                            </s:sequence>
                        </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="Orderline">
                        <s:complexType>
                            <s:sequence>
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="PartNumber" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Qty" type="s:decimal" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="FreeIssue" type="s:boolean" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Discount" type="s:decimal" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="ChargeLine">
                                    <s:complexType>
                                        <s:sequence>
                                            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Code" type="s:string" />
                                            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="Value" type="s:decimal" />
                                        </s:sequence>
                                    </s:complexType>
                                </s:element>
                            </s:sequence>
                        </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I figured out I had to do something like the following:

```
$order = array( 
    'company' => '10',
    'orders' => array(
        'SalesOrdersSalesOrder' => array(
            'CustomerNumber'        => '12345234',
            'OrderNumber'           => '0000001',
            'Currency'              => 'EUR',
            'CustomerComment'       => 'Dit is de comment',
            'FirstName'             => 'Lex',
            'LastName'              => 'Test',
            'Street'                => 'Teststraat 12',
            'ZipCode'               => '1231df',
            'City'                  => 'Testing',
            'Country'               => 'NL',
            'Discount'              => 11.11,
            'ChargeHeader'          => array(
                'Code'          => '001',
                'Value'         => 99.99
            ),
            'OrderLine'             => array (
                'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                'Qty'           => 1,
                'FreeIssue'     => false,
                'Discount'      => 1.11,
                'ChargeLine'    => array(
                    'Code'          => '001',
                    'Value'         => 33.33
                )
            ),                            
            'OrderLine'             => array (
                'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                'Qty'           => 1,
                'FreeIssue'     => false,
                'Discount'      => 1.11,
                'ChargeLine'    => array(
                    'Code'          => '001',
                    'Value'         => 33.33
                )
            ),                            
            'OrderLine' => array (
                'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                'Qty'           => 1,
                'FreeIssue'     => false,
                'Discount'      => 1.11,
                'ChargeLine'    => array(
                    'Code'          => '001',
                    'Value'         => 33.33
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

However when I try to post this to the Client i get the following response back:

> The SalesOrder element has incomplete content. List of expected
>   modular elements: ChargeHeader, Orderline.

In the wsdl it sais the following about ChargeHeader:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="Orderline">
<s:complexType>
```

So I was wondering how to make the following work? I thought a complexType was an array but it's probably something else.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you need to give the element ChargeHeader to the request only you can set is as null. And some reading for [complexTypes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp). And don't you need to response or send xml back to the wsdl as it is a xml styled of communication?

Comment: @WouterVeen I am using SoapClient in php:
 $client = new \SoapClient('address of wsdl');
 $client->Start( $order );

Comment: Oke i think you wil find your awnser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780543/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-php-soapclient-call)

Answer (score 0):

You can't include multiple values with the same key in an array in PHP. Each one will overwrite the previous one.

The WSDL says that both `SalesOrdersSalesOrder` and `Orderline` should be an array of those values.

Also, it should be `Orderline` not `OrderLine`.

```
$order = array(
    'company' => '10',
    'orders' => array(
        'SalesOrdersSalesOrder' => array(
            array(
                'CustomerNumber'        => '12345234',
                'OrderNumber'           => '0000001',
                'Currency'              => 'EUR',
                'CustomerComment'       => 'Dit is de comment',
                'FirstName'             => 'Lex',
                'LastName'              => 'Test',
                'Street'                => 'Teststraat 12',
                'ZipCode'               => '1231df',
                'City'                  => 'Testing',
                'Country'               => 'NL',
                'Discount'              => 11.11,
                'ChargeHeader'          => array(
                    'Code'          => '001',
                    'Value'         => 99.99
                ),
                'OrderLine'             => array(
                    array (
                        'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                        'Qty'           => 1,
                        'FreeIssue'     => false,
                        'Discount'      => 1.11,
                        'ChargeLine'    => array(
                            'Code'          => '001',
                            'Value'         => 33.33
                        )
                    ),
                    array (
                        'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                        'Qty'           => 1,
                        'FreeIssue'     => false,
                        'Discount'      => 1.11,
                        'ChargeLine'    => array(
                            'Code'          => '001',
                            'Value'         => 33.33
                        )
                    ),
                    array (
                        'PartNumber'    => '01-001-000-42',
                        'Qty'           => 1,
                        'FreeIssue'     => false,
                        'Discount'      => 1.11,
                        'ChargeLine'    => array(
                            'Code'          => '001',
                            'Value'         => 33.33
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hee @jjok you are right about the overwrite, however this unfortunately did not solve the problem of the missing ChargeHeader and OrderLine.

Comment: You also have the formatting of `SalesOrdersSalesOrder` wrong. I've updated my answer.