# How do I send an array in SOAP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapui, soap-client

I have a PHP file, which sends SOAP request

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://xyz');
$client->call('example', array('param1'=>'value2')
```

I want to do this same request using SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope [..]>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">example</param1>
         <param2 xsi:type="xsd:anyType">
            ??
         </param2>
      </urn:call>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I encode the above example in XML?

Comment: look at the answer from a previous question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577795/passing-array-to-soap-function-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be something like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope [..]>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">example</param1>
         <param2 xsi:type="xsd:anyType">
            <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">value2</param1>
         </param2>
      </urn:call>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` and then send the array as a string representation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is a nice PHP SOAP client function: `$client->__getLastRequest()`

It showed that, the request is built like this:

```
<param2 xsi:type="ns2:Map">
    <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
        <key xsi:type="xsd:string">param1</key>
        <value xsi:type="xsd:string">param2</value>
    </item>
</param2>
```